# cqlsh: Copy command error ImportError: No module named cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to world of Cassandra and was trying to import a csv data file to my newly created cassandra server on windows 7 for learning purpose, i was following datastax online tutorial for the same and got stuck on 
https://academy.datastax.com/courses/installing-configuring-and-manipulating-keyspace/copying-external-data-tables-development

When i tried to copy a csv file it gives me error

```
cqlsh> use musicdb
   ... ;
cqlsh:musicdb> copy album(title,year,performer,genre,tracks)
           ... from 'album.csv'
           ... with header = true;

Error starting import process:

Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
can only join a started process
cqlsh:musicdb> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\lib\multiprocessing\forking.p
y", line 373, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\python\lib\multiprocessing\forking.p
y", line 482, in prepare
    file, path_name, etc = imp.find_module(main_name, dirs)
ImportError: No module named cqlsh

cqlsh:musicdb>
```

My album.csv file is in same folder as cqlsh.exe

Comment: remove " header = true " condition and try to execute the command.

Comment: Still getting the error, that condition is there because album.csv file contains headers

Comment: Same problem here on Windows 8.1, Cassandra & cqlsh version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627309/pickling-error-running-copy-command-cqlshell-on-windows/